# Dataframe date display issue using shiny with python

Tags: python, py-shiny

i'm new to programming, with objective to learn some basics using Python and R skills for data processing and machine learning. I already made one first project using R and shiny package to implement dashboard for results consultation. few time ago, i decided to switch to Python.

I'm currently facing an issue, trying to display a dataset extracted from an excel file. i don't understand the dates values displayed like presented in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD6Kr.png)

here the correponding code

```
from shiny.express import input, render, ui
import pandas as pd
import xlrd 


df_patient = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\rdesb\OneDrive\Bureau\MyAPP\dashboard\db_patient.xlsx", 
                           index_col="Indice")


#INTERFACE GRAPHIQUE

ui.page_opts(title="DashBoard Plume", fillable=True)

with ui.nav_panel("Informations Patients"):
    ui.h2("Informations Patients")
    @render.data_frame  
    def patients_df():
        return render.DataGrid(df_patient)  

        
with ui.nav_panel("Plot2"):

    with ui.layout_columns():  

        with ui.card():  
            ui.card_header("Card 1 header")
            ui.p("Card 1 body")
            

        with ui.card():  
            ui.card_header("Card 2 header")
            ui.p("Card 2 body")
```

I tried in a python console to reproduce the code, but seems okay. i tried to convert using several method the initial date value before, but nothing really change. Maybe something i don't get in the method.

Thanks a lot for the help

Greetings

i tried to convert the date column using xlrd package , didn't work.

i also tried to convert the date values in the excel file as str following : "dd-mm-yyyy" and then converting it using the following code :

```
df_patient["Date de naissance"] = pd.to_datetime(df_patient["Date de naissance"], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

and that went even worst.